# Fill null values based on the two column values -pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have these two column (image below) table where per `AssetName` will always have same corresponding `AssetCategoryName`. But due to data quality issues, not all the rows are filled in. So, the goal is to fill null values in `categoriname` column.

[image]

So the desired results should look like this:

[image]

The problem is that I can not hard code this as `AssetName` is a couple of thousand different values. So I'm looking for something more dynamic way that can fill the NAs if it has at least one example of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [first](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#first) window function to return the first **non-null** value of the
`AssetCategorieName` column.

```
df = df.withColumn(
    'AssetCategorieName',
    F.expr('first(AssetCategorieName, true) over (partition by AssetName)')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use first() window function to achieve this, combined with coalesce to only updates the null values:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DateDataFrame").getOrCreate()
data = [("Kabelleng", "OB10341_000 - Sling "), ("Kabelleng", None), ("Kabelleng", None), ("Kabelleng_2", "OB20121_000 - Sling"), ("Kabelleng_2", None), ("Kabelleng_2", "OB20121_000 - Sling (2)")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['AssetName', 'AssetCategoryName'])
w = Window.partitionBy("AssetName")
df.withColumn("AssetCategoryName", coalesce(col("AssetCategoryName"), first("AssetCategoryName", True).over(w))).show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+
|AssetName  |AssetCategoryName      |
+-----------+-----------------------+
|Kabelleng  |OB10341_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng  |null                   |
|Kabelleng  |null                   |
|Kabelleng_2|OB20121_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng_2|null                   |
|Kabelleng_2|OB20121_000 - Sling (2)|
+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+
|AssetName  |AssetCategoryName      |
+-----------+-----------------------+
|Kabelleng  |OB10341_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng  |OB10341_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng  |OB10341_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng_2|OB20121_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng_2|OB20121_000 - Sling    |
|Kabelleng_2|OB20121_000 - Sling (2)|
+-----------+-----------------------+
```